# obtener un resultado especifico de posible combinaciones de elementos de una lista

Tags: python-3.x

tengo una lista de números quiero saber si la suma de alguna combinación de ellos da un número especifico si es así lo muestre por pantalla esos números y si no que muestre no hay combinación posible
la lista es [1484.22, 108232.76, 176396.21, 24198.48, 169730.89, 678014.29, 290686.27, 230137.01, 44312.82, 13455.77, 28043.32, 192772.68, 18959.6, 25437.53, 541800.77, 12484.72, 57927.72, 409054.79, 40875.61, 71816.21, 113477.16, 222382.1, 7257.94, 143278.25, 2273.06, 118080.24, 45247.6, 133151.58, 267.97, 1018.53, 50602.21, 19182.73, 373.29, 14702.22, 4041.68, 80831.78, 1189.09, 20255.8, 46619.66, 5016.87, 23460.55, 109208.0, 107395.87] su suma da 4.405.135,85

el código que tengo es el siguiente

```
import pandas as pd

lista_trabajar = pd.read_excel('preproceso.xlsx')

monto_a_trabajar = lista_trabajar.iloc[:, -1]
monto = monto_a_trabajar.tolist()
monto_A_Buscar = 1346675.28
resultado = []

print (monto)

def suma(monto, monto_A_Buscar):
    for i in monto:
        resultado.append(i)
        resul = sum(resultado)
        if resul == monto_A_Buscar:
            return resultado
        else: print ('no salio')
```

Comment: Por principio general no se usa "==" con punto flotante; la práctica es preguntar si la diferencia en menor a un cierto limite, porque la diferencia entre 2.0000000000 y 2.00000001 se puede deber a redondeo, aproximaciones o problemas de representación, o sea, a fallas de implementación, no de la realidad física que queremos representar

Comment: ¿Pueden repetirse los valores para llegar al resultado?

Comment: @CandidMoe no es necesario que sea muy preciso es dinero así que serían dos dígitos nomas 
No pueden repetirse porque cada monto representa una cuenta distinta

Comment: Por lo que dijo Candod Moe, suelo preferir sacrificar un poco la velocidad del programa por un "flotante de base 10": decimal.Decimal

Answer (score 1):

Tengo este algoritmo de backtracking que obtiene el resultado, sin usar dos veces el mismo valor:

```
def buscar(valor, lista, acc = None):
    #
    #   lista es una lista orden descendente
    #   de elementos.
    #
    if acc is None:
        acc = []

    for i in range(len(lista)):
        falta = valor - sum(acc) - lista[i]
        if falta > 0:
            acc.append(lista[i])
            last = len(acc)
            acc = buscar(valor, lista[i+1:], acc)
            if falta:
                acc = acc[:last]
        elif falta == 0:
            acc.append(lista[i])
            break
    return acc
```

Es un algoritmo recursivo que recibe el valor a obtener, la lista de valores disponibles (ordenada descendente) y una lista `acc` en la cual ir acumulando el resultado deseado.

En cada iteración se calcula la suma parcial con `acc` y `lista[0]`. Si el resultado da justo lo buscado, se agrega el valor a la `acc` y se retorna con la solución encontrada.

Si el resultado es menor, se agrega a `acc` el valor recién examinado y se llama recursivamente pasando la lista (un elemento más corta) y el resultado (un elemento más largo).

Si la llamada no retorna el resultado deseado, ya no lo encontraremos por esta senda. Deshacemos las actualizaciones a `acc` hechas aquí y dentro de las llamadas recursivas y pasamos al siguiente elemento de la lista. Está es la parte de backtracking.

La función siempre retornará una lista; para saber si es la respuesta precisa, hay que calcular su suma y compararla contra lo deseado.

Esta modalidad tiene la ventaja de que al menos siempre tendrás la lista de valores más cercana al valor deseado.

#### Demo

Esta demo prueba a obtener todos los valores de 1 -> 49 combinando la lista `[1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 19, 44]`

```
def buscar(valor, lista, acc = None):
    #
    #   lista es una lista orden descendente
    #   de elementos.
    #
    if acc is None:
        acc = []

    for i in range(len(lista)):
        falta = valor - sum(acc) - lista[i]
        if falta > 0:
            acc.append(lista[i])
            last = len(acc)
            acc = buscar(valor, lista[i+1:], acc)
            falta = valor - sum(acc)
            if falta:
                acc = acc[:last]
        elif falta == 0:
            acc.append(lista[i])
            break
    return acc

lista = [1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 19, 44]
lista.sort(reverse=True)

for i in range(1, 50):
    x = buscar(i, lista)
    if i == sum(x):
        print(i, x)
    else:
        print(i, " Sin solución")
```

produce:

```
1 [1]
2 [2]
3 [2, 1]
4 [4]
5 [4, 1]
6 [4, 2]
7 [4, 2, 1]
8 [8]
9 [9]
10 [9, 1]
11 [9, 2]
12 [9, 2, 1]
13 [9, 4]
14 [9, 4, 1]
15 [9, 4, 2]
16 [9, 4, 2, 1]
17 [9, 8]
18 [9, 8, 1]
19 [19]
20 [19, 1]
21 [19, 2]
22 [19, 2, 1]
23 [19, 4]
24 [19, 4, 1]
25 [19, 4, 2]
26 [19, 4, 2, 1]
27 [19, 8]
28 [19, 9]
29 [19, 9, 1]
30 [19, 9, 2]
31 [19, 9, 2, 1]
32 [19, 9, 4]
33 [19, 9, 4, 1]
34 [19, 9, 4, 2]
35 [19, 9, 4, 2, 1]
36 [19, 9, 8]
37 [19, 9, 8, 1]
38 [19, 9, 8, 2]
39 [19, 9, 8, 2, 1]
40 [19, 9, 8, 4]
41 [19, 9, 8, 4, 1]
42 [19, 9, 8, 4, 2]
43 [19, 9, 8, 4, 2, 1]
44 [44]
45 [44, 1]
46 [44, 2]
47 [44, 2, 1]
48 [44, 4]
49 [44, 4, 1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Demo 2

Aplicado al problema que te aflige:

```
lista = [1484.22, 108232.76, 176396.21, 24198.48, 169730.89, 678014.29, 290686.27, 230137.01, 44312.82, 13455.77,
         28043.32, 192772.68, 18959.6, 25437.53, 541800.77, 12484.72, 57927.72, 409054.79, 40875.61, 71816.21,
         113477.16, 222382.1, 7257.94, 143278.25, 2273.06, 118080.24, 45247.6, 133151.58, 267.97, 1018.53, 50602.21,
         19182.73, 373.29, 14702.22, 4041.68, 80831.78, 1189.09, 20255.8, 46619.66, 5016.87, 23460.55, 109208.0,
         107395.87]
lista.sort(reverse=True)
x = buscar(1346675.28, lista)
print(sum(x), x)
```

produce:

```
1346637.46 [678014.29, 541800.77, 118080.24, 7257.94, 1484.22]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

que da un valor bastante cercano al desaeado.

Comment: mil graciasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: nunca había tenido en cuenta hacer un algoritmo recursivo para resolver la situación