# Error ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, lista

Estoy tratando de realizar un programa que pida el peso de paquetes y los vaya asignando a motos sin pasarse del peso de 50kg, la cosa es que al final acabe mostrando el nº de la moto ,el peso de los paquetes que lleva, y el peso total de la carga de cada moto.He utilizado random ya que me exigen cierta aleatoriedad a la hora de escoger,es decir que lo necesito si o si. Lo que he intentado es realizar una copia de los paquetes totales para poder descartar un paquete que no quepa en una moto pero no descartarla para el resto,pero a la hora de eliminar de la copia un paquete que no cabe me dice que el elemento no existe en la lista.

```
import random as random

v=list()

k=0

paq = list()
copia=list()

x=int(input("Dame el peso de cada paquete,una vez introducido presiona enter para introducirel siguiente,pulsa 0 para parar:  "))

#pedir el peso de los paquetes
while x > 0:
    
    paq.append(x)
    x=int(input("Dame el peso del siguiente paquete,una vez introducido presiona enter para introducirel siguiente,pulsa 0 para parar:  "))

    
print()
print("Tenemos los paquetes con los siguientes pesos",paq)
print()

j=0 #nº de moto


while len(paq)!=0:
    copia=paq
    
    j=j+1
    k=0
    while len(copia)!=0:
        
        ordenados=sorted(copia)
        menores=ordenados[:3]
        i=random.choice(menores)
        
        if k + i <=50:
            v.append(i)
            k=k+i
            paq.remove(i)
            copia.remove(i)
        
        if k + i > 50:
            copia.remove(i)
        
        if k + i > 50 or k + i <=50 and len(copia)==0: #si ya no quedan paquetes en copia
            print("Para la moto ",j," se han asignado los paquetes que tienen los siguientes pesos ",v," .Peso total moto:",k)


print("Fin del programa")
```

Comment: Cuando estás creando la variable copia en realidad no es una copia de la lista sino otra referencia a la misma lista. Para crear la copia haz `copia = paq.copy()`.

Comment: muchas gracias !!, lo que pasa esque ahora el error me sale mas tarde, antes me salia en el primer copia.remove y ahora me sale en el segundo.

Comment: Estudia esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557853/obtener-un-resultado-especifico-de-posible-combinaciones-de-elementos-de-una-lis/557901#557901

Answer (score 0):

Te complicas demasiado:

```
import random as random
paq = [int(x) for x in input("Lista de pesos separados por espacios: ").split()]
j = 0
while paq:
    moto = []
    while paq:
        idx = random.randint(0, len(paq) - 1)
        if paq[idx] + sum(moto) <= 50:
            moto.append(paq.pop(idx))
        else:
            j += 1
            break

    if moto:
        print(f"Para la moto {j} se han asignado los paquetes que tienen los siguientes pesos:")
        print(moto)
        print("Peso total moto:", sum(moto))
```

En `moto` tenemos la lista de los paquetes asignados a la moto actual (moto número `j`).

La lista parte vacía y vamos extrayendo elementos de `paq` para ver si dan el total buscado. En tal caso, se agregan a la lista `moto`.

Si el paquete sobrepasa el límite, entonces se rompe el ciclo y se imprime la moto tal como esta.

Este método no es óptimo; no intenta reducir el número total de motos ni busca exhaustivamente otro paquete para completar la carga.

produce:

```
Lista de pesos separados por espacios: 10 10 20 12 14 15 23 20 24 45
Para la moto 1 se han asignado los paquetes que tienen los siguientes pesos:
[14, 23]
Peso total moto: 37
Para la moto 2 se han asignado los paquetes que tienen los siguientes pesos:
[45]
Peso total moto: 45
Para la moto 3 se han asignado los paquetes que tienen los siguientes pesos:
[10, 20, 15]
Peso total moto: 45
Para la moto 4 se han asignado los paquetes que tienen los siguientes pesos:
[20, 24]
Peso total moto: 44
Para la moto 5 se han asignado los paquetes que tienen los siguientes pesos:
[10, 12]
Peso total moto: 22

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @Mateo. Cierto; fue un rezago de la primera solución que di.